# django flag for mobile request?

Tags: django, mobile

I'd like to have a flag variable to test mobile page in django.

Currently we need to use the flag on both python views, django templates, javascripts, handlebar templates.

It will be something like `{% if is_testing_mobile %} do something.. {% endif %}`

We deliver only few pages differently for mobile and for pc. 
(most pages are covered by bootstrap's fluidness)

How can we set up a variable to switch on-off mobile/pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://github.com/saschwarz/minidetector,

```
from minidetector import detect_mobile

@detect_mobile
def my_mobile_view(request):
    is_mobile = False
    if request.mobile:
        is_mobile = True
        #do something with mobile
    render(request, 'page.html', {'is_mobile': is_mobile})
```

**page.html:**

```
{% if is_mobile %} 
     render the mobile css 
{% else %}
     render the pc css
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Adding a Middle-ware which would set some parameter to Request object if it is coming from a Mobile Device.

You could write a Middle-ware yourself as mentioned in previous answer or use this Third part App: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-user_agents

Note: Other apps are also available with different levels of functionality for Mobile detection: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/mobile/